# Items on Destop is not displayed

Tags: 12.04, .desktop

After I login my Ubuntu 12.04 , Desktop appears but none of the items in the Desktop is displayed. But it exists there and is visible if we go through /Home/Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Ubuntu 13.10, in Unity, but with Gnome installed *(so it might work)*.

You can enable it in [`dconf-editor`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor/) - *(search for `desktop` with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)* - but it is just as simple to run - note the `set` commands may restart file manager:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

To turn off again:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

To get the current value:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons
```

You can use [`unity-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) as well, but to change what appears on the desktop:
[image]

Also, in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, make sure this line is present and is going the right path:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

Also rememver that you can't view any files starting with `.`, or ending with `~` on the desktop.

Comment: op may ask about the files ended with ~ for example `filename.txt~`,which are usually not appeared on the desktop.